# Getting median of column values in each group

Tags: sqlite, group-by, median

I have a table containing user_id, movie_id, rating. These are all INT, and ratings range from 1-5.

I want to get the median rating and group it by user_id, but I'm having some trouble doing this.

My code at the moment is:

```
SELECT AVG(rating)
FROM (SELECT rating
      FROM movie_data
      ORDER BY rating
      LIMIT 2 - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM movie_data) % 2
      OFFSET (SELECT (COUNT(*) - 1) / 2
              FROM movie_data));
```

However, this seems to return the median value of all the ratings. How can I group this by user_id, so I can see the median rating per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives the required median:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movie_data2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE movie_data2 AS
SELECT user_id, rating FROM movie_data order by user_id, rating;

SELECT a.user_id, a.rating FROM (
SELECT user_id, rowid, rating
FROM movie_data2) a JOIN (
SELECT user_id, cast(((min(rowid)+max(rowid))/2) as int) as midrow FROM movie_data2 b
GROUP BY user_id
) c ON a.rowid = c.midrow
;
```

The logic is straightforward but the code is not beautified. Given encouragement or comments I will improve it. In a nutshell, the trick is to use `rowid` of SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Am I right in thinking that `a.user_id` is making use of the row id? Could you briefly explain what this allows us to do? Also, this produces some duplicates, i.e. a user seems to have more than one median rating. Can you explain why this is? Example output pastebin: http://pastebin.com/9fvih7Q2

Comment: `rowid` is used as the row number, but in fact it is fixed when creating the table. So, indeed, there was an error in the code, I have tried to fix it, using a fresh TEMPORARY table. Try it again?

Answer (score -1):

This is not easily possible because SQLite does not allow correlated subqueries to refer to outer values in the LIMIT/OFFSET clauses.

Add WHERE clauses for the `user_id` to all three subqueries, and execute them for each user ID.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT user_id,AVG(rating) 
FROM movie_data
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY rating
```

Comment: You should add some text explaining what this answer does and why it provides a solution to the specific problem. Code dumps are rarely ever of use to other people.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as far as I'm aware the `AVG` function returns the mean and not the median.